# Making a Rock Paper Scissors game in Python - How to reduce repetition and make it more effective?

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, rock-paper-scissors

I am a "new" coder to Python - saying this because I got stuck in the tutorial hell - and I saw that doing projects was a way of consolidating what I had learnt from those tutorials, so here I am.

I made a little rock paper scissors game, and I am kind of a novice when it comes to making my code effective. So please be as critical as possible with my it (obviously only constructive criticism), so in the future I *may* get better at this. By the way, if you have any other project that you could suggest for my level I would be glad to do it :)

## main.py

```
# My attempt on making rock paper scissors
from multiplayer_mode import multiplayer
from player_cpu import playerVsCPU

choose_Gamemode = ""
text = ""
user_input = ""
temp = False

while choose_Gamemode != "exit":
    choose_Gamemode = input("Choose your game mode (\"mul\" for multiplayer, \"solo\" to play against computer, \"exit\" to exit.): ")

    if choose_Gamemode.lower() == "mul":
        text = multiplayer()
        user_input = input("Do you want to add the date of today (Y/N)?")
        
        if user_input.upper() == "Y":
            user_input = input("Enter the date of today: ")
            temp = True

        with open("victory_log.txt", "a") as file:
            if temp:
                file.write(f"\nAs of {user_input} the winners are (from first to last):\n")
            file.write(f"{text}\n")
            


    elif choose_Gamemode.lower() == "solo":
        playerVsCPU()
    elif choose_Gamemode.lower() == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input! Try again!")

print("Thank you for playing the game!")
```

## multiplayer_mode.py

```
def multiplayer():
    import random
    import os
    
    win = False
    player1 = ""
    player2 = ""
    player1_Choice = ""
    player2_Choice = ""
    victory_cond = {"scissors":"paper", "paper":"rock","rock":"scissors"}

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    player1 = input("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors! Enter player 1's name: ")
    player2 = input("Input player 2's name: ")

    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    while win != True:

        player1_Choice = input(f"{player1}'s turn (Enter rock, paper or scissors): ")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        player2_Choice = input(f"{player2}'s turn (Enter rock, paper or scissors): ")
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    
        if player1_Choice.lower() == player2_Choice.lower() and player1_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.keys() and player2_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.values():
            print("It's a draw! Try again!")

        elif player1_Choice.lower() != player2_Choice.lower() and player1_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.keys() and player2_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.values():
            for i, j in victory_cond.items():
                if player1_Choice.lower() == i and player2_Choice.lower() == j:
                    win = True
                    print(f"{player1} wins over {player2} using {player1_Choice} against {player2_Choice}!")
                    return player1
                else:
                    win = True
                    print(f"{player2} wins over {player1} using {player2_Choice} against {player1_Choice}!")
                    return player2

        else:
            print("Oops, invalid input! Try again!")
```

## player_cpu.py

```
def playerVsCPU():
    import random
    import os

    win = False
    list_of_rcp = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    victory_cond = {"scissors":"paper", "paper":"rock","rock":"scissors"}

    while win != True:

        user_input = input("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors! Your turn (Enter rock, paper or scissors): ")
        cpu_choice = random.choice(list_of_rcp)

        if user_input.lower() == cpu_choice.lower():
            print("It's a draw! Try again!\n")

        elif user_input.lower() != cpu_choice.lower() and user_input.lower() in victory_cond.keys() and cpu_choice.lower() in victory_cond.values():
            for i, j in victory_cond.items():
                if user_input.lower() == i and cpu_choice.lower() == j:
                    win = True
                    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
                    print(f"You win against the computer using {user_input} against {cpu_choice}!\n")
                
                else:
                    win = True
                    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
                    print(f"Computer wins against you using {cpu_choice} against {user_input}!\n")
            
        else:
            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
            print("Oops, invalid input! Try again!\n")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if you have any other project that you could suggest

Here's a fun one.
Implement [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

## docstring

```
# My attempt on making rock paper scissors
```

This is nice enough, I suppose.

Python has a special form called a docstring,
which you may have seen on functions and classes.
Here, you might re-phrase this as module-level docstring:

```
"""My attempt on making rock paper scissors"""
```

## lint

```
choose_Gamemode = ""
```

[Pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell it `choose_gamemode`.

Similarly for `player2_choice` and `player_vs_cpu`.

## quoting

```py
... = input("Choose your game mode (\"mul\" for multiplayer, \"solo\" to ...")
```

Clearly those `\` backwhacks work fine.
But they're ugly.
Often you can use the "other" kind of quote so they're no longer needed:

```py
... = input('Choose your game mode ("mul" for multiplayer, "solo" to ...')
```

If you had been using
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
it would have noticed that detail
and canonicalized the spelling for you.

## [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

You only care about the downcased (`.lower()`) game mode.
So assign that *once*, rather than re-computing it several times.

## use the standard libraries

This is a little weird:

```
            user_input = input("Enter the date of today: ")
```

Prefer to use the
[datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects)
library.

```
import datetime as dt
...
            today = dt.date.today()
```

## context manager

Kudos on using a `with` to ensure the file you open'ed will be properly close'd.

## pick one approach for control flow

```
while choose_gamemode != "exit":
    ...
    elif choose_gamemode.lower() == "exit":
        break
```

I recommend that you use *just* the `while` test,
or that you use *just* the `break` (inside `while True:`).
Using both leads to confusion, and hard-to-diagnose bugs.

On which topic, the inconsistent downcasing (in some places but not others)
is not a good practice.

## imports at top

```
def multiplayer():
    import random
    import os
```

Please don't do that.

[Pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)
explains that imports belong at top-of-file.

Lint with [ruff](https://pypi.org/project/ruff)
to have weird items called out.
Your code should lint clean when you execute `$ ruff *.py`

Use [isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort) to organize your imports properly.

## ANSI escapes

```
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

I'm glad to see you've been trying out `if` expressions.

Forking a child process is a pretty heavy weight approach,
compared to `print(end=chr(27) + "[2J", flush=True)`.
If you search pypi.org, you'll find there's more than
one package that would be happy to help you put convenient names on
[ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences)
escape sequences.

Also, DRY!
You use this expression several times.
Use `def` to package it up as a tiny helper function,
and make several calls to that function.

## a boolean is already a boolean expression

```
    while win != True:
```

Prefer:

```
    while not win:
```

When you have a boolean variable, like `win`,
there's usually little need to explicitly compare it to `True` or `False`.

## canonicalize

```
        if player1_Choice.lower() == player2_Choice.lower() and player1_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.keys() and player2_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.values():
```

Same issue as noted above.
Assign the downcased string from the get go:

```
        player2_choice = input(f" ... ").lower()
```

Also, that third conjunct is kind of weird.
Recall that this is a true statement: `set(victory_cond.keys()) == set(victory_cond.values())`.
Given that 1st is identical to 2nd, and 1st is valid,
we can conclude that 2nd is valid.
Also, randomly switching from keys to values leaves the reader scratching their head.
Also, doing a key lookup takes O(1) constant time,
but asking for all values will take O(N) linear time.
Doesn't matter for a dict of size three,
but there *would* be a noticeable speed difference
if you copy-n-pasted such code into a situation
where you're manipulating a "large" dictionary.

Consider validating user input immediately.
That will simplify the {win, lose, draw} logic.

Consider breaking out a helper function
which prompts for a response
and which *guarantees* it's returning a valid response.

## choose names carefully

This is not a great identifier.

```
    list_of_rcp = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
```

Resist the urge to put "list" in the name of something that's a `list`,
or "dict" when it's a `dict`.

I have no idea what that letter "c" denotes.

DRY -- these three items appear elsewhere as keys!

Prefer:

```
    rps = list(victory_cond)
```

Or maybe call it `weapons`.
Now you're all set for when we add
[Spock and Lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors#Additional_weapons).

DRY: You should define `victory_cond` just once, in one source file,
and `import` it as needed.

## next step

You have very similar "adjudicate game play" logic in two modules.
Re-work it a little, so that "computer" can be seen as "player 2".

Answer (score 5):

#### Only define variables where they are needed.

Python doesn't require you to declare variables in advance. And there is no need to assign them a value either.

For instance the declaration with initialization of the variable:

```
player1 = ""
```

this variable is not read, the first we see of it is:

```
player1 = input("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors! Enter player 1's name: ")
```

#### Don't repeat data

Take:

```
victory_cond = ["scissors":"paper", "paper":"rock","rock":"scissors"]
```

If you simply define `["scissors", "paper", "rock"]` then you can find the winner by simply checking if the choice is one before the other in a round robin fashion. Of course using the current `victory_cond` allows more flexibility, but I don't think that is needed here.

#### Don't repeat actions, use variables

If you create e.g. `player_choice_lower = player1_Choice.lower()` then you have less code and the computer has less work to do. In IDE's there is often a way to perform this refactoring without having to replace each statement.

#### Don't use booleans vars if you already can exit a loop otherwise

```
while win != True:
```

is correct. However, once `win` **is** assigned `True` it is followed by `return player1` or `return player1`, skipping the check entirely. So `while True` would work just as well.

#### Don't do two things at once

```
    if player1_Choice.lower() == player2_Choice.lower() and player1_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.keys() and player2_Choice.lower() in victory_cond.values():
```

This code is hard to read, it checks two things at once. It is better to first test if the input is valid and then continue checking if it is a draw, i.e. both choices are equal.

### Convert strings to other types of variables early

One way to do this is to use *enums*. You convert the input, say `player1_input` to input by creating a function that returns an enum value or `None` if the input doesn't represent an existing enum value.

Comparing an enum is a very lightweight operation which is better than repeatedly comparing strings all the time. For this kind of game it won't make any difference of course, but this is more about the *idea* of converting to the right type of variable.

#### Don't copy code, use functions

This kind of statement can be found repeatedly in the code:

```
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

This should be replaced by a function, probably called `clear_screen` or something similar. Any changes for clearing the screen will now be localized. For instance, you could imagine that only real OS with vt100 compatible terminals will be used and that a control can be sent instead.

Comment: From when does Python have a var keyword?

Comment: `If you simply define {"scissors", "paper", "rock" } then you can find the winner by simply checking if the choice is one before the other in a round robin fashion`
A set is unordered so you would have a hard time to define "one before". To do that, you would need to use a list.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury &  
rdesparbes Yeah, that's showing that Python is not my goto language. That's Java, 'cause it has `goto` ;)